# Repeating the object in a list of transitive verbs

Tags: transitive-verbs, direct-objects

> You have received this proposal. Please decide whether you would like
>   to accept it or reject it.

Is it correct to repeat the object `it` in this  sentence or should I skip it until the last verb? For example:

> Please decide whether you would like to accept or reject it.

Comment: Either is acceptable.

Comment: Personally I would drop the 'it' altogether, "Please decide whether you would like to accept or reject."

Comment: Accepting is a rather binary act. If you do not accept you are rejecting. You could cut the whole sentence down to *Please decide whether you would like to accept.* That said, more generally, transitive verbs can share a single mention of an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good writing in English - especially in corporate contexts - calls for simplicity.

Please decide whether you would like to accept or reject it. Personally, I would not accept that sentence as I believe it can be improved stylistically.

When you write it more simply, you get:

***Please decide whether you would like to accept it or not***.

That is the short-form, which is considered standard, for: 
Please decide whether you would like to accept it or ***not accept it***.

This way of writing it is more succinct and **follows the rule of not having to repeat an entire verb phrase**. [see below]

This style solution has the benefit of removing the issue about repeating or not repeating /it/.

In Hamlet, we get: **To be or not to be, that is the question**. So beautiful, isn't it?

Had the Bard written: /To be or not, that is the question/, the poetry would have been lost even though it would have been grammatical.

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/clauses-short-forms

2. **We often leave words out if we think they are just repeating things that don't need repeating**:

I asked him to come but he wouldn’t. = ... he wouldn’t come.

Comment: I'm probably just not tracking but isn't the Hamlet reference going against you in this? It's 'repeating an entire verb phrase', no?

Comment: @Unrelated Right, you are not tracking. :) The Shakespearean phrase is highly poetic. The question was for a context, that clearly is not. Ergo, the OP's question should not repeat the entire thing.

Comment: Right, but you don't explain that. It looks like you are just trying to show off that you know ... the most known line of the most known English poet. If someone is coming here genuinely looking for an answer they will read your answer and then get confused by what they expect to be an example and is instead a counterexample, though it is never described as such.

Comment: @Unrelated I was very explicit about poetic/non-poetic and I am not responsible for people's reading abilities regarding subtleties. And obviously the OP and three others thought it was clear.

Answer (score 1):

Since both the object and what's standing for the object are short (namely *proposal* and *it*), either is acceptable.

> Please decide whether you would like to accept or reject it.
>
> Please decide whether you would like to accept it or reject it.

In both cases it is clear that the reader is being asked to accept or reject the proposal.

If the object were more complex, one should take care to help keep them clear in the reader's mind. For example,

> You have received the motion, the amendments, and the Secretary's notes. Please vote for or against the motion, and for or against the amendments.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that both sound correct but I'd be inclined to use the second version (accept or reject it).

The first is 'verb-object or verb-object' while the second is '(verb or verb)-object'. The first sounds like two possible actions, to which the response might be, 'actually I'd like to do both'. The second sounds more like a single action with exclusively alternate verbs and no option to choose both.

(Hoping someone with a better grasp of grammar can either edit this to explain what I'm trying to say or delete it if it is rubbish!)